# How to get this functionality to work

Tags: css, html

I have some div, inside of which has a couple of tables as below

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <table id="table1"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
            <table id="table2">
                <tr></td></td></td></td></tr>
                <tr></td></td></td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

When table2 has lot of rows, am using overflow in css to show the horizontal scroll bars. This scrollbars I am applying to div2, so when we scroll, table1 also scrolls down. How to make sure that table1 is always fixed, that is, it does not scroll down?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css
    table {max-height: 200px;}

```
tbody {
 height: 180px;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

html

```
<table id="table2">
 <tbody>
  <tr></td></td></td></td></tr>
  <tr></td></td></td></td></tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

For more in depth explanation, see: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: am not able to get the horizontal bars..they show up when i use it with div2 though

Comment: both the tables and the tbody need to have heights assigned... double check that, and the link i posted.